# Error : 3737 ,Name requires more than 30 bytes in LATIN internal form?

Tags: jdbc, teradata

I want to fastload in teradata with JDBC.
I used preparestatements.
My table name is :`XXX_XXXX_XXXXXXXX_XXXXXXXX`
and none of my column names are bigger than 30 chars too.
But I got this error.
I dont understand why.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your tablename is probably too long, when you check http://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/jdbcug_chapter_2.html#BABIIEAG you'll find

**JDBC FastLoad creates two temporary error tables with the following naming convention: ._ERR_1 and ._ERR_2**

and

**The name of the destination table in the Teradata Database that is to be used by JDBC FastLoad CSV must not exceed 24 characters because of the name of the two error tables created by JDBC FastLoad CSV**

If this was a standard FastLoad i would simply add ERRORTABLES and use my own error table names, but this seems not to be available in JDBC FastLoad.
So your only option is to create the table with a shorter name, FastLoad it and then submit a RENAME TABLE.

Comment: so you say it should be under 24 characters?

Comment: when I substring the table name to 20 chars the load is okey and _ERR_! and ERR_2 was created, but they are empty.

Comment: When the error tables are empty, this means there were no errors during load :-)